# storing an JSON array in java code array in android

Tags: java, php, android, json

I want to store the json array sent by php code in java  array  in android. My php code is working perfectly fine but in the app I get name:    as the output. I want to display the names in the texview for checking purpose. Also I want to work with the namesby accessing them one by one.

Php code:

```
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```

Java code:

```
public class Salary {
    public static final String DATA_URL1 = "http://********.com/name.php?salary=";
    public static final String KEY_name = "name";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY1 = "result";   
}
```

This is a method of my Name.java

```
private void showJSON(String response) {
    String name = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Salary.JSON_ARRAY1);
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(i);
            name = collegeData.getString(Salary.KEY_name);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textViewResult1.setText("Name:\t" + name);
}
```

Comment: Will you please put sample json result string which get as response.

Comment: What is the problem? You want to store data? Text doesn't display in your textview?

Comment: I want to store the data..

Comment: Use Gson introduce by google.

Comment: Have you tried searching first? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I have getting the output as name:     ,although my app work in  other cases where I want to display a single value but in array it fails as in the above case..

Comment: Is it possible to display the names in Toast?

Answer (score 0):

**Use GSON Library**

```
    ArrayList<Salary> salaryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        salaryArrayList = new Gson().fromJson(response, new TypeToken<Salary>() {}.getType());

    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

> Then use salaryArrayList to get values.
>   Download GSON jar from this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm)

Comment: Salary is not a model class actually